# Data insertion acts differently with two similar entities

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I have two entities: *Movie* and *Person* in my simple Movie App. While I try to add initial data to database something strange is happening. Even though my both entities are very similar, inserting people works fine, while inserting movies result in having 11 (while array of 7 is passed as argument) movie elements with null fields in it:

```
I/System.out: [Movie{id=23, title='null', genre='null', 
posterResource=null}, Movie{id=24, title='null', genre='null', 
posterResource=null} ... Movie{id=33, title='null', genre='null', 
posterResource=null}]
I/System.out: [Person{id=23, firstName='Brad', lastName='Pitt', age=55, 
imgResource=2131165277}, Person{id=24, firstName='Edward', 
lastName='Norton', age=49, imgResource=2131165286}, ... , Person{id=33, 
firstName='Joaquin', lastName='Phoenix', age=44, imgResource=2131165293}]
```

Interior of my LocalDataSource, where I insert data:

```
private AppDatabase mDataBase;

public LocalDataSource(Context mContext) {
    mDataBase = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(mContext);
    mDataBase.personDao().deleteAllPeople();
    mDataBase.movieDao().deleteAllMovies();
    setupTestMovieData();
    setupTestActorsData();
    setupTestMovieActorRelationship();
    System.out.println(getAllMovies());
    System.out.println(getAllActors());
}

public List<Movie> getAllMovies(){
    return mDataBase.movieDao().loadAllMovie();
}

public List<Person> getAllActors(){
    return mDataBase.personDao().loadAllPeople();
}

public List<Person> getActorsFromMovie(long movieId){
    return mDataBase.actorMovieJoinDao().getActorsFromMovie(movieId);
}

private void setupTestMovieData() {
    MovieDao dao = mDataBase.movieDao();
    dao.insertMovie(getTestMovieArray());
}

private Movie[] getTestMovieArray() {
    Movie[] movies = new Movie[7];
    movies[0] = new Movie("Fight club", "Thriller", R.drawable.fightclub);
    movies[1] = new Movie("Prestige", "Thriller",R.drawable.prestige);
    movies[2] = new Movie("500 days of Summer","Drama", R.drawable.the500daysofsummer);
    movies[3] = new Movie("Seven","Detective", R.drawable.kiler);
    movies[4] = new Movie("Inception","Action", R.drawable.pulpfiction);
    movies[5] = new Movie("American Hustle","Crime", R.drawable.phantomthread);
    movies[6] = new Movie("Her","Drama", R.drawable.dancerinthedark);
    return movies;
}

private void setupTestActorsData(){
    PersonDao dao = mDataBase.personDao();
    dao.insertPeople(getTestActorArray());
}

private Person[] getTestActorArray() {
    Person[] actors = new Person[11];
    actors[0] = createPerson("Brad", "Pitt", "18/12/1963", R.drawable.bradpitt);
    actors[1] = createPerson("Edward", "Norton", "18/8/1969", R.drawable.edwardnorton);
    actors[2] = createPerson("Helena", "Bonham-Carter", "26/5/1966", R.drawable.helenabonhamcarter);
    actors[3] = createPerson("Joseph", "Gordon-Levitt", "17/2/1981", R.drawable.josephgordonlevitt);
    actors[4] = createPerson("Zooey", "Deschanel", "17/1/1980", R.drawable.zooeydeschanel);
    actors[5] = createPerson("Christian", "Bale", "30/1/1974", R.drawable.christianbale);
    actors[6] = createPerson("Leonardo", "DiCaprio", "11/11/1974", R.drawable.leonardodicaprio);
    actors[7] = createPerson("Morgan", "Freeman", "1/6/1937", R.drawable.morganfreeman);
    actors[8] = createPerson("Amy", "Adams", "20/8/1974", R.drawable.amyadams);
    actors[9] = createPerson("Scarlett", "Johansson", "22/11/1984", R.drawable.scarlettjohansson);
    actors[10] = createPerson("Joaquin", "Phoenix", "28/10/1974", R.drawable.joaquinphoenix);
    return actors;
}

private Person createPerson(String firstName, String lastName, String date, Integer imgResource){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
        gregorianCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Person(firstName, lastName, gregorianCalendar, imgResource);
}
```